# how to include source packages in a sub-project to the web.xml in the main project

Tags: java, xml, maven, spring-mvc, web.xml

I googled my question online but many answers are related to Spring MVC and these answers do not meet my expectation. I'm using Maven and I want to use plain java not any framework like Spring, etc.

I'm trying to build a java dynamic web application project and I split the project into let's say 2 parts SubProject (name of sub-project) and MainProject (name of main project) (actually the main project is composed of 5 sub-projects but that's not related to my question, so I simplified the case). I want to treat SubProject as a library for the MainProject and all projects can be built using Maven. The SubProject is not a dynamic web application project so it does not have a deployment descriptor web.xml and the MainProject is a dynamic web application project with a web.xml.

Now suppose I write a java filter MyFilter.java in the package com.my.package in SubProject and I need to configure it in the web.xml in the MainProject so that MyFilter can work for certain url pattern(s). The problem arise because I don't know how to include source packages in the SubProject into the MainProject in web.xml.

I do know how to do that in Spring MVC by including the following configuration in spring.xml:
    `<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.package" />`
where com.my.package is a source package in SubProject. Also in web.xml, includes:
    `<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>`

Since I don't want to use Spring framework, I'm looking for some way to configure my web.xml similar to what I did in spring.xml. Does any one have an idea how to include source packages (and classes) in a sub-project to the main project in java web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do the following:

- Configure MainProject to build a WAR: `<packaging>war</packaging>` in pom.xml
- Configure SubProject to build a JAR: `<packaging>jar</packaging>` in pom.xml
- Add SubProject as dependency to MainProject:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>groupId.of.SubProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>SubProject</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You can use filters from SubProject in MainProject's web.xml:

```
<filter>  
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.my.package.MyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Yes. I figured it out by myself but thank you anyway.